# How to populate the textbox

Tags: javascript, python

this is my idea.

for instance, i have this on my list

```
nameList = [
{ 'id': 1 , 'name': "Fred" },
{ 'id': 2 , 'name': "Dale" },
{ 'id': 3 , 'name': "Denmark" }
]
```

and I have this on my template

for example:

```
Name: <input type='text' name='name'>
ID: <input type='hidden' name='id'>
```

What I want to do here is that, whenever i type the name 'Fred' in first textbox, automatically,the id would become 1. if i type 'Dale', it would become 2. the reason I want to do this kind design is that I only want the id to be saved to the database. I think i will need to use javascript but I do not have any idea how to do it. Please... your help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: how are you building this `nameList`

Comment: Stack overflow is not code service. please tell what you tried to do and share your code.

Comment: you have to use javascript to send data between browser and server using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to comment so posting it as answer but not sure what exactly you want.

If you are looking for auto-complete type input like you type and it gives you the suggestion and then you select any one of the suggestions then below example can help you. Here you have the flexibility to what you want to show to the user and what you want to use as value which later on you can save in DB.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc2/docs/forms/search/

If this is not what you want then please explain your question a little bit and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

may be you want this:

```
>>> def get_tag(name):
...     values = [x for x in nameList if name in x.values()]
...     return "Name: <input type='text' name='{}'>\nID: <input type='hidden' name='{}'>".format(values[0].get('name'), values[0].get('id'))
... 
>>> print get_tag('Dale')
Name: <input type='text' name='Dale'>
ID: <input type='hidden' name='2'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack-overflow is not a code service. Try to do something first, then ask a question.

Anyway this may be helpful.

HTML:

```
Name: <input type='text' id='myName'>
<input type='hidden' id='myId'>
```

JS:

```
var myName = document.getElementById('myName');
var id = document.getElementById('myId');

var nameList = [
  { id: 1 , name: "Fred" },
  { id: 2 , name: "Dale" },
  { id: 3 , name: "Denmark" }
]

myName.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  var value = e.target.value;
  value = value.toLowerCase();

  for(var i=0; i<nameList.length; i++){
    var name = nameList[i].name.toLowerCase();

    if(name == value) {
        id.value = nameList[i].id;
      alert(nameList[i].id + ': ' + nameList[i].name);
      break;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/62h0qrqd/